# Kendo Export as PDF generation

Tags: php, jquery, kendo-ui

intermediate kendo plugin to create PDF getting blank pdf when we are passing base64 data to pgp file through jQuery post request to php file

Comment: Please post your code whatever you have tried.

Comment: kendo.drawing.drawDOM("#content_mergeReport", {
            allPages: true,
            forcePageBreak: ".page-break",
            paperSize: "A4",
            scale: 0.6,
             landscape: false,
            Portrait :true,
            repeatHeaders: true,
            multiPage: 'true',
            margin: {left: "1cm", top: "1.5cm", right: "1cm", bottom: "2.5cm" },
              
            /*template: $("#page-template").html()*/
            
                     
                })
          })

Answer (score 0):

this is my sample code for kendo

kendo.drawing.drawDOM("#content_mergeReport", {
            allPages: true,
            forcePageBreak: ".page-break",
            paperSize: "A4",
            scale: 0.6,
             landscape: false,
            Portrait :true,
            repeatHeaders: true,
            multiPage: 'true',
            margin: {left: "1cm", top: "1.5cm", right: "1cm", bottom: "2.5cm" },

```
        /*template: $("#page-template").html()*/
           template: kendo.template($("#page-template").html())(  
            {  
                pageNum: "",  
                totalPages: "",  
                FIRSTDATE: startDate1,  
                TYPE: typeofuser,  
                ENDDATE: endDate1,  
                USER: context.get('practicedetails').Name,  

            })
      })
      .then(function (group) {
          return kendo.drawing.exportPDF(group, {
          });
      })
      .done(function (data) {
    var data1 = {};
    var parts = data.split(";base64,");
    data1.contentType = parts[0].replace("data:", "");
    data1.base64 = parts[1];
    data1.filename =  $scope.filename;      

  });
```